# Insert data into a dictionary by reading a json file

Tags: json, dictionary, xamarin.forms

I have vector json file that contains specific data for each user (some records are part of the same user), I would like to read it and deserialize it inside a dictionary (I have to insert both Key and Value from the file)

Comment: It would really help if you provided a sample of the json you're working with, and the data structure you want to deserialize into.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that here is the json data

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Add the json file into your shared project , and set its `Build Action` as `Embedded resource`.
2. Use [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to generate the model class.

   ```
   public class GlossDef
    {
        public string para { get; set; }
        public List<string> GlossSeeAlso { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlossEntry
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string SortAs { get; set; }
        public string GlossTerm { get; set; }
        public string Acronym { get; set; }
        public string Abbrev { get; set; }
        public GlossDef GlossDef { get; set; }
        public string GlossSee { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlossList
    {
        public GlossEntry GlossEntry { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlossDiv
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public GlossList GlossList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Glossary
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public GlossDiv GlossDiv { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Glossary glossary { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize the json into object .

   ```
   var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
   Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNameSpace.test.json");
   string text = "";
   using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
   {
       text = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }

   Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(text);
   ```